# How can I get parameters of an article in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to design the article page of JOOMLA 3.1, but I haven't managed to succeed. 
How can I achieve this? 
And how can I get the parameters of an article?

Like, when I have article test I want to do something like this

```
$this->article->get('title');
```

I already tried to Google but I can't find any proper information. Is there someone who can explain this to me?

Comment: What does var_dump($this); give you?

Comment: this gives me all kind of data including templateDetails.xml data, but no article info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the design, you should do a [Template Override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)

Then, you will see in:

```
components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php
```

that the params are defined and called like so:  `

```
$params  = $this->item->params;

$var1 = $params->get('param_name_1');
$var2 = $params->get('param_name_2');
$var3 = $params->get('param_name_3');
```

Comment: oke thanks, but when i override the template do i still have to do this in the main page? <jdoc:include type="component" />

Comment: no, it has nothing to do with the *index.php* of your template. You're simply overriding the view of the component. You can do this for any component or module. Have a read of the link I provided in my answer which will explains more in-depth ;)

Comment: i did what the link told me, but stil it doesn't override. he stil reads the one in components

Comment: does your folder structure look like this: `templates/template_name/html/com_content/article/default.php` ?

Comment: o so stupid of me, i had mod_content instead of com_content :P Thank you very much. you are my hero :P